# Docker container doesn't detect changes to the shared folder?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I have shared my host development directory to the container directory. So when I am making changes to my local folder, I can see the changes inside the container via a shell. But the container doesn't reflect that on running it.

What am I missing?

This is the section where changes have been made -

```
docker-compose.yml
------------------

  ports: 
            - "80:80"
        volumes: 
            - /var/www/goldilocks/goldilocks-backend:/var/www/app:consistent
        depends_on: 
            - mongo_db
```

Comment: "But the container doesn't reflect that on running it." - what does that even mean in that context?

Comment: Is it possible to edit code and reflect that in the running container instantly?

Comment: The language runtime has to support it.  In many popular languages (Go, Java, Rust, C++, ...) you have to recompile the program anyways, and so rebuilding an image isn't especially an imposition.